# how to find the last grouped digit in a string in bash

Tags: bash

This is a follow-up question to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51923800/10247894) question, regarding how to know the number of grouped digits in string.

In bash,

How can I find the last occurrence of a group of digits in a string?
So, if I have

```
string="123 abc 456"
```

I would get

```
456
```

And if I had

```
string="123 123 456"
```

I would still get

```
456
```

Comment: Look up some awk examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 grep -o '[0-9]\+' file|tail -1
```

- `grep -o`  lists matched text only
- `tail -1` output only the last match

well, if you have string:

```
grep -o '[0-9]\+' <<< '123 foo 456 bar' |tail -1
```

Comment: The OP specifically said he’s using a string, not a file.  I would update the answer to make use of the herestring operator.

Comment: @CJK default grep uses BRE. that's why we need the `\+`

Comment: `\+` isn't part of BRE, it's a GNU extension to BRE. "Pure" BRE would be `[0-9][0-9]*`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a regex in Bash:

```
$ echo "$string"
123 abc 456
$ [[ $string =~ (^.*[ ]+|^)([[:digit:]]+) ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
456
```

If you want to capture undelimited strings like `456` or `abc123def456` you can do:

```
$ echo "$string"
test456text
$ [[ $string =~ ([[:digit:]]+)[^[:digit:]]*$ ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
456
```

---

But if you are going to use an external tool, use `awk`.

Here is a demo of Bash vs Awk to get the last field of digits in a string. These are for digits with `' '` delimiters or at the end or start of a string.

Given:

```
$ cat file
456
123 abc 456
123 123 456
abc 456
456 abc
123 456 foo bar
abc123def456
```

Here is a test script:

```
while IFS= read -r line || [[ -n $line ]]; do
    bv=""
    av=""
    [[ $line =~ (^.*[ ]+|^)([[:digit:]]+) ]] && bv="${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
    av=$(awk  '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if (match($i, /^[[:digit:]]+$/)) last=$i; print last}' <<< "$line")
    printf "line=%22s bash=\"%s\" awk=\"%s\"\n" "\"$line\"" "$bv" "$av"
done <file
```

Prints:

```
line=                 "456" bash="456" awk="456"
line=         "123 abc 456" bash="456" awk="456"
line=         "123 123 456" bash="456" awk="456"
line=             "abc 456" bash="456" awk="456"
line=             "456 abc" bash="456" awk="456"
line=     "123 456 foo bar" bash="456" awk="456"
line=        "abc123def456" bash="" awk=""
```

Comment: Works perfectly on Bash 3.2.57 (OS X) What version of Bash do you have?

Comment: I am running `GNU bash, version 4.4.19(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)`. Hm, it's hard to believe since you are saying there **must** be `[[:space:]]` with your regex. So if there is only one "number group" at the beginning of the string, this shouldn't match in my opinion.

Comment: @PesaThe: Sorry! I misread your example test string. You are right, my regex this morning would not work for that. Fixed.

Answer (score 2):

Without external utilities (such as `sed`, `awk`, `...`):

```
$ s="123 abc 456"
$ [[ $s =~ ([0-9]+)[^0-9]*$ ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
456
```

`BASH_REMATCH` is a special array where the matches from `[[ ... =~ ... ]]` are assigned to.

---

*Test code:*

```
str=("123 abc 456" "123 123 456" "123 456 abc def" "123 abc" "abc 123" "123abc456def")

for s in "${str[@]}"; do
    [[ $s =~ ([0-9]+)[^0-9]*$ ]] && echo "$s -> ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
done
```

*Output:*

```
123 abc 456 -> 456
123 123 456 -> 456
123 456 abc def -> 456
123 abc -> 123
abc 123 -> 123
123abc456def -> 456
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use this `sed` to extract last number in a line:

```
sed -E 's/(.*[^0-9]|^)([0-9]+).*/\2/'
```

**Examples:**

```
sed -E 's/(.*[^0-9]|^)([0-9]+).*/\2/' <<< '123 abc 456'
456

sed -E 's/(.*[^0-9]|^)([0-9]+).*/\2/' <<< '123 456 foo bar'
456

sed -E 's/(.*[^0-9]|^)([0-9]+).*/\2/' <<< '123 123 456'
456

sed -E 's/(.*[^0-9]|^)([0-9]+).*/\2/' <<< '123 x'
123
```

**RegEx Details:**

- `(.*[^0-9]|^)`: Match 0 or more characters at start followed by a non-digit OR line start.
- `([0-9]+)`: Match 1+ digits and capture in group #2
- `.*`: Match remaining characters till end of line
- `\2`: Replace it with back-reference #2 (what we captured in group #2)

Comment: Hm, `sed -E 's/(^|.*[^0-9])([0-9]+).*/\2/' <<< '123 abc 456'` gives me `123` :O

Comment: Damn, that was a typo :), .Should have copy/pasted from my terminal. It is corrected now

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do it with pure Bash:

```
shopt -s extglob            # enable extended globbing - for *(...)

tmp=${string%%*([^0-9])}    # remove non-digits at the end
last_digits=${tmp##*[^0-9]} # remove everything up to the last non-digit

printf '%s\n' "$last_digits"
```

Comment: I couldn't come up with parameter expansion alone to do this at the time. Nice one ++

Answer (score 0):

This is a good job for parameter expansion:

```
$ string="123 abc 456"
$ echo ${string##* }
456
```

Comment: That will fine last word non necessarily last number.

Answer (score 0):

A simple answer with `gawk`:

```
echo "$string" | gawk -v RS=" " '/^[[:digit:]]+$/ { N = $0 } ; END { print N }'
```

With `RS=" "`, we read each field as a separate record.
Then we keep the last number found and print it.

```
$ string="123 abc 456 abc"
$ echo "$string" | gawk -v RS=" " '/^[[:digit:]]+$/ { N = $0 } ; END { print N }'
456
```