# how to find the last grouped digit with decimals in a string in bash

Tags: bash

This is a follow up question to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51934004/10247894) question, regarding how to find the last grouped digit in a string in bash.

4 of the solutions worked perfectly for the original question, but I realize that the solution would be more adaptable if there is added support for decimals.

So, if I have

```
string="123 abc 456.1"
```

I would get

```
456.1
```

and if I had

```
string="123 abc 456.1."
```

I would still get

```
456.1
```

And if I had

```
string="123 abc 456."
```

I would just get

```
456
```

Additionally,

```
string="1.2 1.3"
```

would just return

```
1.3
```

Comment: Why is `456` the output for `123 abc 456. 1`? You are adding support for floats, that doesn't change the fact that `1` is still the last number.

Comment: @PesaThe sorry about the error, fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this with GNU [grep](/questions/tagged/grep) with [pcre](/questions/tagged/pcre) support and using [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) for *here-string* `<<<`  :

```
string="123 abc 456.1"
bc -l <<< "$(echo "$string" | grep -oP '.*?\K\d+\.\d*')*1" | awk 'END{print}'
```

(works in all cases)

Comment: What would I need to change to the above code to get the `nth` float in the string? You don't need to edit the solution, i'm just trying to learn so I don't ask repetitive questions

Comment: `.. awk 'NR==2{print}'`

Answer (score 2):

You can adapt linked solution to get a decimal number like this:

```
# utility function
lastNum() {
    grep -Eo '[[:digit:]]+(\.[[:digit:]]+)?' <<< "$1" | tail -1
}

# Call it as

lastNum '1.2 1.3'
1.3

lastNum '123 abc 456.1.'
456.1

lastNum "123 abc 456."
456

lastNum "123 abc 456.1"
456.1
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk`:

```
$ string="123 abc 456.1"
$ awk '{print $NF+0}' <<< $string
456.1
$ string="123 abc 456."
$ awk '{print $NF+0}' <<< $string
456
$ string="1.2 1.3"
$ awk '{print $NF+0}' <<< $string
1.3
```

`$NF+0` tells `awk` to take the last element and add 0 in a decimal context.
If the last element is not a number, the return value will be 0.