# How to find largest group of numbers in a string in bash

Tags: bash

This is a follow-up question to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51934004/10247894) question. It seems that string manipulation in bash consistently confuses me.

**How can I find the largest group of numbers in a string in bash?**

So, if I have

```
"123 abc 456"
```

I would get "456"

And if I have

```
"456 abc 123"
```

I would still get "456".

And if I had

```
"1.005 1.23 4"
```

I would get "4"

Also, if you see my previous questions, they are very similar to this one. What is your recommendation between awk, sed, regex, pure bash etc. for learning how to solve most my previous issues myself?

Comment: In your last example, how/why is 4 larger than 123?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
echo "456 abc 123" | grep -oE '[0-9]+' | sort -n | tail -n 1
```

Explanation:

- `grep -o` - Print just the matching part of a line
- `grep -E` - Use extended regex
- `[0-9]+` - Match one or more digits (this is extended regex)

  - For floats, use `[-+]?[0-9]+\.[0-9]+`, though `sort -n` doesn't handle floats.
- `sort -n` - Numeric sort
- `tail -n 1` - Get last line, i.e. largest number

BTW, a Python version:

```
max((int(s) for s in "456 abc 123".split() if s.isdigit()), default=None)
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there any way to adapt this solution to add support for floats?